# In Pyspark 2, Adding a column based on multiple conditions

Tags: pyspark

I would like to add a column based on conditions. I have a value on `'E_Ref_Value'` but I would like to add a column regarding column `E_Ref_Value` as `E_Ref_Grp`.
Here is the code that I run

```
df=df.withColumn('E_Ref_Grp',f.when((col("E_Ref_Value")>0 & f.col("E_Ref_Value")<31), f.lit(1))\
                            .when((f.col("E_Ref_Value")>30 & f.col("E_Ref_Value")<61),f.lit(2)))
```

I didn't get specific error messages with error codes, couldn't create the column, do you have any suggestions?

Error Message:

```
Py4JError: An error occurred while calling o1509.and. Trace:
py4j.Py4JException: Method and([class java.lang.Integer]) does not exist
at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.getMethod(ReflectionEngine.java:318)
at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.getMethod(ReflectionEngine.java:326)
at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:274)
at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:238)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Comment: If you don't add your error, we probably won't be able to help

Comment: I added the error message

Comment: OK. and error message with my solution ? because my solution is solving this problem.

Comment: I've edited and added the error message I got after applying the solution you suggested.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing `otherwise` with `when`.

```
# create data frame
df = spark.createDataFrame(
[("1","358934","2020"),
("2","38639","2021"),
("21","7675","2026"),
("30","983434","2022"),
("31","234","2023"),
("60","2325","2024"),
("61","4545","2025")], 
("E_Ref_Value","projection","year"))

# show contents of data frame
df.show()
+-----------+----------+----+
|E_Ref_Value|projection|year|
+-----------+----------+----+
|          1|    358934|2020|
|          2|     38639|2021|
|         21|      7675|2026|
|         30|    983434|2022|
|         31|       234|2023|
|         60|      2325|2024|
|         61|      4545|2025|
+-----------+----------+----+

# import necessary functions
import pyspark.sql.functions as f

# apply when otherwise
df1 = df.withColumn("E_Ref_Grp", f.when(((f.col("E_Ref_Value") > 0) & (f.col("E_Ref_Value") < 31)), f.lit(1)). when(((f.col("E_Ref_Value") > 30) & (f.col("E_Ref_Value") < 61)), f.lit(2)).otherwise(f.lit(None)))

# display df1 result
df1.show()
+-----------+----------+----+---------+
|E_Ref_Value|projection|year|E_Ref_Grp|
+-----------+----------+----+---------+
|          1|    358934|2020|        1|
|          2|     38639|2021|        1|
|         21|      7675|2026|        1|
|         30|    983434|2022|        1|
|         31|       234|2023|        2|
|         60|      2325|2024|        2|
|         61|      4545|2025|     null|
+-----------+----------+----+---------+
```

Comment: I still get the same error message and one error more 
IllegalArgumentException: 'when() can only be applied on a Column previously generated by when() function'. This time I get error code atleast

Comment: @EfeTürkoğlu Added demo for the code block shared earlier. It is working as expected

Comment: Yes, thank you. I understood the problem. In the first when function, I used f.when but when I add a new condition with when function again,  I also added f before. That's why I got an error.

Answer (score 0):

You need to write each comparison in parenthesis.
`col("E_Ref_Value") > 0` becomes `(col("E_Ref_Value") > 0)`, etc...

```
df = df.withColumn(
    "E_Ref_Grp",
    when(((col("E_Ref_Value") > 0) & (col("E_Ref_Value") < 31)), lit(1)).when(
        ((col("E_Ref_Value") > 30) & (col("E_Ref_Value") < 61)), lit(2)
    ),
)
```

Comment: I tried this solution but I got the same error. In the error message, there is no specific error code.

Comment: @EfeTürkoğlu I edited the message, added some more details. You need to put every comparison in parenthesis. Is this what you did ?

Comment: I tried the new version also but still not resolved.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can individually break the conditions into booleans and use them to create the required columns

Below is an example of what I mean -

```
df = spark.createDataFrame([0.0,10.0,100.0,32.0,45.0], FloatType())

df = df.withColumn("Cond1_Bool",(F.col("value") > 0) & (F.col("value") < 31))
df = df.withColumn("Cond2_Bool",(F.col("value") > 30) & (F.col("value") < 61))

df = df.withColumn("E_Ref_Grp",F.when(F.col("Cond1_Bool"),F.lit(1)).otherwise(F.lit(2)))

df.show()

+-----+----------+----------+---------+
|value|Cond1_Bool|Cond2_Bool|E_Ref_Grp|
+-----+----------+----------+---------+
|  0.0|     false|     false|        1|
| 10.0|      true|     false|        1|
|100.0|     false|     false|        1|
| 32.0|     false|      true|        2|
| 45.0|     false|      true|        2|
+-----+----------+----------+---------+
```

You can drop the extra columns afterwards